# Using a wildcard as a value itself?

Tags: mysql

Good day guys, I would like to in theory build something like this.

`col1 | col2 | col3 | col...
   %  |   A  |  0.0 | ...
   1  |   %  |  0.2 | ...
   %  |   %  |   %  | ...
   %  |   B  |  0.1 | ...
   2  |   %  |  0.0 | ...`

So when I query it say...

- to select (col1) 1 + wildcard values, it will return row 0, 1, 2, 3.
- or to select (col1) 2 + wildcard values, it will return row 0, 2, 3, 4.

My current work around is a sloppy one where I use a value on the far end of the datatype as the wildcard placeholder. For instance, a few of these columns are MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED so I'm using "16777215" as the wildcard value. And I'm using a query like...

- `select * from TABLE where col1 IN (1, 16777215)`
- `select * from TABLE where col1 IN (2, 16777215)`

But I know this is a very dirty method and I'm slowly approaching my doom as there might be a chance that over time an actual value might take on the wildcard's value.

Is there a better way to approach this? Any form of advice or pointers on what to read up is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Context: It's for a very low level and loose pattern matching kinda thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NULL` as the de facto wildcard value:

```
select * from TABLE where col1 IN (2, 3, ...) OR col1 IS NULL
```

Be careful that this doesn't have unintended side effects (such as getting a `NullPointerException` in the calling code).